# URL redirection after form submitted without inherited params

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a web site using `PHP` and `JQuery Mobile`.
On a page I have a form:

```
 <form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return comprobardatos()" data-ajax="false" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
<p>

  Nombre:
    <input type="text" name="nombre_plato" id="nombre_plato"  value="" size="32" >
<div id="mensajealias"></div><div id="ajaxBusy" style="display: none;"><p><img src="wait.gif"></p></div>
  </p>
<p>Descripción:
  <input type="text" name="descripcion_plato" id="descripción_plato" value=""  size="32"><div id="mensajenombre"></div>
  </p>

<p>Precio 1:
  <input type="text" name="precio1_plato"  value="" onkeypress="if ( isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;" size="32">
  </p>
  <p>Precio 2:
  <input type="text" name="precio2_plato"  value="" onkeypress="if ( isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;" size="32">
  </p>
  <p>Precio 3:
  <input type="text" name="precio3_plato"  value="" onkeypress="if ( isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;" size="32">
  </p>
  <p>Precio 4:
  <input type="text" name="precio4_plato"  value="" onkeypress="if ( isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;" size="32">
  </p>

<p>
  <input type="button" name="clear" data-role="button" data-theme="e" value="Limpiar formulario" onclick="clearForm(this.form);">
  <div id="boton"><input type="submit" data-role="button" data-theme="b"id="insertar" value="Insertar Nuevo Contenido de la Carta" ></div><div id="mensajeboton"></div>
</p>
<p>
          <input type="hidden" name="cadena_plato" value="<?php echo $_SESSION[Region]?>">

          <input type="hidden" name="restaurante_plato" value="<?php echo $_GET['rest']?>">

          <input type="hidden" name="categoria_plato" id="categoria_plato" value="<?php echo $_GET['cat']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
              </p>

            </form>
```

The URL from the page is:

```
http://.../NuevoAdminPlato.php?rest=1&cat=9
```

When the user clicks on the submit button, the page AdminPlatos.php should be shown. This is the part of the code that I am using to go to the page>

```
$insertGoTo = "AdminPlatos.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

But the launched URL is?

```
http://.../AdminPlatos.php?rest=1&cat=9
```

And I don't want to get there the params> `rest=1&cat=9`

I guess this is a `JQuery` issue, but I don't know how to avoid it.

Comment: When you don't want that params, why are you including them to the link? `$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`

Comment: @debute, I am taking it from an example, I was not sure what that line is used for. Thank you, and how could I maintain only the param cat=9?

Comment: It depends, what method your form uses. For now, it is POST, so you can replace that line `$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];` by this one `$insertGoTo .= $_POST['cat'];` and it should works now.

Comment: @debute, thank you, it works now, I have change both $insertGoTo .= lines with: $insertGoTo .= "?id=";
    $insertGoTo .= $_GET['cat']; and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here you have complete block of code...

```
$insertGoTo = "AdminPlatos.php";
if(!empty($_POST['cat'])) {
  $insertGoTo .= '?id=something';
  $insertGoTo .= '&cat='.$_POST['cat'];
  header("Location: $insertGoTo");
}
```

I used `!empty($_POST['cat'])`, because you are going to use just 'cat' and `!empty()` better fit than `isset()`, because 'cat' could be empty, but `isset()` would wtill return true;

Then I used `header("Location: $insertGoTo");`, because you have single one variable and this should be more clear to read.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort.